# Parsing a String with Dynamic Arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using the dynamic spill-down arrays recently introduced in Excel 365, I wrote a super simple formula to parse the characters in a string into single cells.  For example, if I have:

**qwertyuiop$**

in **A1**, I pick a cell and enter:

```
=MID($A$1,ROW(1:11),1)
```

and the formula spills down:

[image]

This avoids entering `=MID($A$1,ROWS($1:1),1)` and manually copy it downwards.

The problem I have is with the number **11**.  I use **11** because I know the length of **A1** is 11.  I would like to change the `MID()` formula to make it adjust to the length of **A1** rather than me re-typing the formula.

I tried:

```
=MID($A$1,ROW(1:LEN(A1)),1)
```

but this fails.  My current work-around is:

```
=FILTER(MID($A$1,ROW(1:9999),1),MID($A$1,ROW(1:9999),1)<>"")
```

which seems like a really dumb way to make **11** a variable.

I offered a VBA solution, but that was rejected.

Comment: Would `INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))` achieve the same?

Comment: @Mokubai  **YES1** ...................Thanks!

Comment: I was just in the process of testing in Office online and posting an answer. It is slightly different to your already accepted answer but I'd say that Scotts answer is slightly more succinct. `INDIRECT` can be a useful tool to know about though.

Comment: @Mokubai the only thing to remember about `INDIRECT` is that it is volatile and will cause the formula to recalc whenever a change is made anywhere in Excel.  While sparse use of it will not impact performance, relying on it too much will.

Comment: @ScottCraner That would explain some of my more... "intriguing" spreadsheets being a bit odd performance wise. Sadly I'm a bit behind the times where versions of office are concerned but I will definitely bear in mind that there may be more efficient options.

Comment: @Mokubai Even with older, the use of `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))` would reduce the use of INDIRECT.  Personally, outside of the workbook and/or worksheet being the variable, I feel the use of INDEX can replace INDIRECT in nearly every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  SEQUENCE

```
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)
```

[image]

What is nice about SEQUENCE is that if you want the array to spill horizontally then you just use:

```
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(,LEN(A1)),1)
```

[image]

---

If you are set on Row then use:

```
=MID(A1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),1)
```

Comment: THANKS!  I will mark ANSWER ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

One method is through use of an `INDIRECT` to evaluate the `LEN()` and concatenate it with your starting range. This is pretty close to your original formula and is an alternative.

```
=MID($A$1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! ......................all three answers are going in my toolbox!